# Copy/paste from system clipboard in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, copy-paste

I'm building a simple electron app to show some text on the screen on top of everything else.
There is a keyboard shortcut that opens a pop-up with text.
I want to add one little function. 
The best case scenario would be: I select some text wherever on my computer and press a dedicated keyboard shortcut and this text shows up in the pop-up. It copies the text and pastes it in the app.
I guess it will be problematic for safety reasons (coping from system clipboard) but maybe there is a way around it? Is it possible to do it? Is there a walk-around that will be similar to the one I described?

In other words, now I need 3 steps: ctrl+C (to copy selected text) ctrl+M (to open the app) ctrl+V (to paste it in the app). Can I reduce it to only one step with only my dedicated keyboard shortcut or to two steps: Ctrl+C + Ctrl+M?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can create an app where the window is not showing ([use parameter show of browser-window](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)),
maybe create a trayicon to visualise that the app is running.

Than define in your app a global shortcut (Ctrl+M) [global-shortcuts in electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts#global-shortcuts).

In your shortcut callback set window to visible and get the clipboard content.
Electron has an api for that, [you can find it here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard#clipboardreadtexttype)

than just add the text to the window